# Free plotter software?

Tags: software-recommendation, free

I have Roland ColorCAMM PC-60.

I'd like to use this thing to cut vinyl. I've spent whole day searching for any free plotting software but the best I've come across was EasySIGN which has way more features I don't need (I use Illustrator to prepare data) for way higher price (I cannot afford).

Is there really nothing free I can use to just import EPS or SVG and hit Cut?

Thanks

Comment: had you try on HP official plotter website?

Answer (score 4):

The only free vinyl cutting software that I know of right now is [Inkcut](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkcut/) for Inkskcape.

Other than that one there isn't a free solution out there.   Your best bet for the price could be [VinylMaster Cut](http://www.vinylmastercut.com/buy/) but I have never used it. I would recommend  [Flexistarter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QV73Z4) which is a lighter version than Flexi but that isn't free nor a plugin for illustrator.  I wouldn't skimp on the software personally but thats just me.

There are some other great ones you might like such as:

- [Omega](http://www.gspinc.com/OMEGA)
- [Casmate](http://www.fcsrl.com/en/Cutting-Plotter-and-Software/casmate-basic.html)
- [SignLab](http://www.cadlink.com/products/signLab/)

Most of the ones I listed you can source used for on Ebay for the dongles that plug into the back of your computer.

If you're pressed to find one for Illustrator the only one I've used and recommend is the one by [Onyx](http://www.onyxgfx.com/products/plug-ins/sign-banner/).  There is [Roland Cutstudio plugin for Illustrator](http://www.rolanddg.com/product/cutting/gx-24/cutstudio.html) but I have never used it but you might consider it. Also, have you checked Roland's site to make sure this isnt any software or [drivers](http://support.rolanddga.com/_layouts/RolandDGA/productdetail.aspx?pm=PC-60) that would work??